# Issue with connecting AJAX with PHP while developing a WordPress plugin

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

So basically I'm trying to make my first plugin in WordPress, and not very familiar with PHP. I want my PHP script to print out a zero, and three buttons, where one adds two to the number, one adds ten and the last button divides by two. I got a 500 HTML response after trying this. Was able to print the zero and buttons, but the AJAX part didn't work.

Edit: I have tried removing quotes around "ajax_object.ajaxurl" and

add_action('wp_ajax_change_number', 'erik_ajax_change_number');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_change_number', 'erik_ajax_change_number');

to

add_action('wp_ajax_erik_change_number', 'erik_ajax_change_number');
add_action('wp_ajax_erik_nopriv_change_number', 'erik_ajax_change_number');

but this is still not working

**myfirstphp.php**

```
<?php

$zero = 0;

//prefixed functions
function erik_print_zero_init(){
    function erik_print_zero(){
        global $zero;
        return $zero;
    }
    add_shortcode('zerohere', 'erik_print_zero');
}
add_action('init', 'erik_print_zero_init');

function erik_add_buttons_init(){
    function erik_add_buttons(){
        return '<button type="button" class="erik_button" name="erik_button1">+2</button>
                <button type="button" class="erik_button" name="erik_button2">+10</button> 
                <button type="button" class="erik_button" name="erik_button3">/2</button>';
    }
    add_shortcode('erik_buttons', 'erik_add_buttons');
}
add_action('init', 'erik_add_buttons_init');


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_enqueue_scripts' );
function so_enqueue_scripts(){
  wp_register_script( 'ajaxHandle', get_template_directory() . '/public_html/wp-content/plugins/myfirstphp/myajax.js', array(), false, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxHandle' );
  wp_localize_script( 'ajaxHandle', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin_ajax.php' ) ) );
}







add_action('wp_ajax_change_number', 'erik_ajax_change_number');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_change_number', 'erik_ajax_change_number');


function erik_ajax_change_number($_POST['name']){
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
        switch ($_POST['name']) {
             $zero;
            case 'erik_button1':
                global  $zero +=2;
                break;
            case 'erik_button1':
                global  $zero +=10;
                break;
            case 'erik_button3':
                global  $zero /=2;
                break;
        }
    }
    wp_die();
}

?>
```

***myajax.js***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.erik_button').click(function(){
        var buttonName = $(this).attr('name');
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_object.ajaxurl",
        action: 'erik_ajax_change_number',
        data:{ name = buttonName},
        success: function(output){
            alert(output);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

Can anyone point out what I did wrong here or give me some tips on troubleshooting?

Comment: You should remove the quotation marks on the variable "ajax_object.ajaxurl". You're making a post to the variable name instead of actually getting the value of it. That's atleast one thing that I can see is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You've to change

```
add_action('wp_ajax_change_number', 'erik_ajax_change_number');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_change_number', 'erik_ajax_change_number');
```

to

```
add_action('wp_ajax_erik_ajax_change_number', 'erik_ajax_change_number');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_erik_ajax_change_number', 'erik_ajax_change_number');
```

check here, https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thank you, but this unfortunately didn't resolve my HTML 500.

Comment: remove quotes here url: "ajax_object.ajaxurl",